# Destructuring from Promise.all into object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, destructuring

I find myself at the moment writing a lot of code like

```js
const arr = await Promise.all([getName(), getLocation(), getDetails()])
const obj = {
    name: arr[0],
    location: arr[1],
    details: arr[2]
}
// send obj to somewhere else
```

which is quite ugly. I was hoping there was something like

```js
const obj = {}
[obj.name, obj.location, obj.details] = await Promise.all([getName(), getLocation(), getDetails()])
```

but this fails. Is there an elegent way to do the destructuring like this?

Comment: this ought to work, as I understand it. Can you clarify what "this fails" means? Is an error thrown? If so, share it, if not share what the result is and how it compares to what you expect.

Comment: It's a pity the accepted answer is hiding the actual problem here which is caused by a missing semicolon. For some reason omitting semicolons is trendy these days, but it leads to a bunch of footguns like this.

Comment: By the way, array destructuring works slightly slower than object destructuring, because array destructuring calls the iterable protocol of the right-hand side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *does* work. You just have to add a semicolon here.

```js
(async () => {
  const obj = {}; // <------------------------------
  [obj.first, obj.second, obj.third] = await Promise.all([1,2,3])
  console.log(obj)
})()
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const [name, location, details] = await Promise.all([getName(), getLocation(), getDetails()]);

const obj = { name, location, details };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await Promise.all([getName(), getLocation(), getDetails()])
    .then(([name, location, details]) => ({ name, location, details }));
```